# Функция strtotime, текущая дата и прошлая дата

Tags: php

Не могу понять принцип работы функции.
Есть две переменные

```
$date_end = "2023-01-04";
$current_date = "2022-12-29"
```

Если вывожу strtotime то получаю следующее

```
$strtotime($date_end) = 1669053600
$strtotime($current_date) = 1672250400
```

Почему текущая дата больше $date_end, хотя передаю 4 января 2023 года, дата еще не наступила

Comment: покажите целиком код, как вы это делаете, и таймзона какая.  а то у меня выводится `1672790400, 1672272000`

Comment: а ваш первый таймстамп вообще на 21 ноября указывает

Comment: Да, похоже что проблема не в strtotime а где-то в коде, и туда уже приходит неправильная дата. Было бы правильно сделать вывод, навроде ````echo($date_end . " = " . strtotime($date_end));````

Comment: у вас переменную $strtotime запихана функция - её покажите. Системная функция strtotime() без значка $